# VBA Sending the Enter key to an HTMLInputElement

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, automation

I have what I hope will be a simple question.  I have a bit of code where I load a web page and enter a number into a field in IE.  It is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub GettingCashAvail()

Dim IE          As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim HTMLDoc     As HTMLDocument
Dim IEField     As HTMLInputElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.navigate "https://website.com/login.aspx"

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Do Until IE.statusText = "Done"
    DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Set IEField = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ucGetAccountNumber_txtAccountNumber")

IEField.Value = "#########"
```

Now this field supports pressing enter to move to the next page.  I could dim a second object for the submit button and then do something like IESubmit.Click to enter the information and navigate to the new screen, but what I'd like to do is somehow send the return key.  Here is the portion of the source from the web page that I'm interested in:

```
onkeypress="return clickButton(event,&#39;ucGetAccountNumber_btnSubmit&#39;)"
```

Do you think there is any way to simply send the enter key?  Thanks for the ideas if so, if not I can just get that submit button set to a second input object.

Comment: `call GettingCashAvail?`

Comment: I have the same question. Were you able to find a solution to this specific question? I need to mimic either a "tab" or "enter" keyboard entry. But when I use ``SendKeys``, it enters directly in the VBA console.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use:

```
IE.Visible = True
Application.SendKeys "~" '## send the "Enter" keystroke
```

But in my attempts to use `SendKeys` method, they're not very reliable, and most people will suggest using different methods.

I think personally it is preferable to create another object variable and invoke the button's `.Click` method, as you indicated.

Comment: No dice.  I actually tried another slight variation of this.  I also tried simply adding Chr(10) to the text field with predictable results - no results.

Comment: Do you suppose there is a way to achieve this using the "FireEvent" method?

Comment: Never heard of it. Why not just go the easy route, create another object variable to represent the button that needs to be clicked, and then invoke the `.Click` method?

Comment: You already know how to solve this problem. You're looking for alternative ways to do it, when the API natively supports a reliable solution.  Just use the `.Click` if `SendKeys` doesn't work.  NB: there's a reason most people will tell you to avoid `SendKeys` :)

Comment: That is what I went with.  Unfortunately the documentation on the HTML object library is fairly poor, or I couldn't find it anyway.  I did find another method, but it invovled Windows APIs and some creative keyboard hijaking that brought it's own troubles.  I decided to move on.  Thanks for the help and suggestions though.

Comment: No problem. Yes, keyboard hijacking is usually something to avoid :)